# Array in constructor, how to write out at another file. (polymorphism)

Tags: java

I am new for java. 
Now I would like to try array in the constructor, but when i type at another file, there got error. Anyone can tell me why? First Part:

```
    public String title;
public String[] actor = new String[2];
public String director;
//Constructor

public Movie(String title, String[] actor, String director){
this.title = title;
this.actor = actor;
this.director = director;}
```

Another part:

```
    list1 = new Movie("title","actor 1" ,"actor 2","director");
listing[0] = list;
```

However this part was error, anyone can tell me what wrong ? 
I have try alot of method but still can't make it.

Comment: When the compiler generates an error, the error has a meaningful message. Read it. If you don't understand it, post it. In that case, the error probably is something like *Constructor Movie(String, String[], String) is not applicable to the arguments (String, String, String, String)*, which precisely explains why your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor call `new Movie("title","actor 1" ,"actor 2","director");` would call a constructor with the following parameter set: `(String, String, String, String)`, which definitely does not match `new Movie(String, String[], String)`.

You might be interested in using [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html). Then, you'd have to modify your constructor signature like this:

```
public Movie(String title, String director, String... actors)
```

and call it with

```
new Movie("title","director","actor 1" ,"actor 2")
```

This is legal Java expression.

Comment: This look interesting
I will try it when I get more use to in on java! 
Thank Alot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor Movie() expects an array as second argument, and you're passing a String. Pass an array, eg.:

```
list1 = new Movie("title", new String[]{"actor1", "actor2"}, "director");
```

or if you have an array of actors already, as in:

```
String[] actors = {"actor1", "actor2"};
```

pass it as second argument:

```
list1 = new Movie("title", actors, "director");
```

Answer (score 0):

your constructor is fine but the way you are creating the object of Movie is wrong. in Java anything between two double quotes (" ") is a String object. So the way you are creating the object of Movie gives an impression that you have a constructor which takes 4 String parameters. 
I wont suggest to use varargs since you are still learning java. Using varargs as Andrei suggested would actually compile and run your code correctly and give you an impression that the parameters lik e you types is an array representation.  IN java if you need ot create arrays directly you do something like this

```
new String[]{"str1", "str2", "str3"}
```

ans like wise for any type whose array you want to create.